# Android :desapeared bar chart with achartengine

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I'm trying to dispaly a bar chart with achartengine ,but i'm getting transparent bars with no colers ,and i'm just getting numbers (y coordiantes ) in the top of the bar.
I used this code :
class SalesStackedBarChart

```
  public class SalesStackedBarChart extends AbstractDemoChart {
  /**
   * Returns the chart name.
   * 
   * @return the chart name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return "Sales** stacked bar chart";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the chart description.
   * 
   * @return the chart description
   */
  public String getDesc() {
    return "The monthly** sales for the last 2 years (stacked bar chart)";
  }

  /**
   * Executes the chart demo.
   * 
   * @param context the context
   * @return the built intent
   */
  public Intent execute(Context context) {
    String[] titles = new String[] { "2008", "2007" };
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
  /*  values.add(new double[] { 14230, 12300, 0, 15244, 15900, 19200, 22030, 21200, 19500, 15500,
        12600, 14000 });
         values.add(new double[] { 5230, 7300, 0, 10540, 7900, 9200, 12030, 11200, 9500, 10500,
        11600, 13500 });*/
     values.add(new double[] { -65, -71, 0, -80, -90, -20, -10, -95, -89, -75,
    -95, -35,-45,-68 });
     values.add(new double[] { -71, -65, 0, -80, -90, -10, -20, -95, -89, -75,
                -95, -35,-45,-68 });

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN };
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    setChartSettings(renderer, "Monthly sales in the last 2 years", "Month", "Units sold", 0,
        12, -100, -30, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    // renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
renderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f);


return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,
    Type.STACKED);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please follow these step



XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        //incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(1); 
        //incomeRenderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID);
        double max = timetaken1.get(timetaken1.size()-1);
        incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(15);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Question vs Time Chart");
        multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Questions");
        multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.RED);
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.RED);
        multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
        multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
        multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(max+2);
        multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(18);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
        int a[]={40,40,0,10};
        multiRenderer.setMargins(a);
        multiRenderer.setTextTypeface("Arial", Typeface.BOLD);
        multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Time Taken");
        //multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);  
        multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.1);
        //multiRenderer.setBarWidth(25);
        //multiRenderer.setScale(25);

        multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-1);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(10);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);

        int i=0;
        for(i=0; i< question1.size();i++){
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i,question1.get(i));

            //multiRenderer.addYTextLabel(i,question1.get(i),25); 
        }   

        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer); 
        View v=ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer,Type.DEFAULT);
        chartview.addView(v);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ,but it didn't work for me .And with my code i'm getting an upside bar chart .